# Pot light failure

Tags: recessed-lighting

I installed a string of 12 pot lights from Costco and they worked fine for 4 months.  Yesterday I flipped the switch, the lights came on and went off immediately.  I have power at all the lights, I have bypassed the switch, but no light...and suggestions?

Comment: Type of pot light is important here: led? cfl? incandescent? Are there any external transformers/ballast?

Comment: Start tracing your electrical voltage from point-to-point to point until you figure out where it stops getting voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using an NCVT. If you "have power" and it doesn't work, you've lost the neutral somewhere.

Check all the connections inside the housings:

Near the bottom of a standard can light there are three screws. Remove them and the entire inner tin-can should pull down out of the ceiling.  This provides you access to the junction box that is part of the lamp; where its connections are that you need to inspect.